# Add events to the buttons in the ComboBox Events

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a form which includes AdobeShockwave player for play some YouTube videos by clicking on the different buttons.
I've set a comboBox (This allow user to choose what events need to show it in the AdobeShockwave) and 3 Radio buttons (for see the rest of the buttons and videos).
I've already put codes in the Visual Studio and compiled and it was true.
But i have a problem.
Just imagine i put some codes which includes : when user choose number one in the combobox (index 1) and then choose the radio button, Set the Text of Buttons.
But now i wanna do something and put some codes which includes, When user choose button 1 , specific video show in the Shockwave and when user click on the button 2, Show the specific video and ... .
I know i have to put this code in the Button event :

```
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            axShockwaveFlash.Movie = "Video's URL";
```

But i code above happen if :
1. ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1 
2. RadioButton1.Checked = true
3.Then when user click in the button 1 Show the video.

I put my image which can help you.
Thanks in advance for your Help.
[image]

And these are my codes :

```
    private void radioPage1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {

            /* Show/Display the numbers of row in the form*/
            lbl1.Show();
            btn1.Show();
            /* Change the label of the Events*/
            lblEvents.Text = "StarCraft II ProLeague 2016 S1 :";
        }
```

**Update**
There is no one to answer my problem ?